# Without writing the test cases is good approach to test the product or software in Agile process?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, testcase, agile-testing, agile

We have Several projects are lined up along with the product testing. Due to time urgency and time constraints the test cases are not writing up for some functions and UI and doing the testing without test cases. In this situation I felt and observed some bugs are raising in the client SIT environment testing. I know it is kind of bad approach in the testing.

Can anyone suggest me your feedback and ideas and this to avoid the leakage in the client environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Agile approaches suggest [Test-Driven-Development](https://less.works/de/less/technical-excellence/test-driven-development.html), but at least you should practice some form of technical excellence to satisfy the following Agile principles:

> Continuous attention to **technical excellenc**e and good design enhances
>   agility.
>
> https://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html

Personally, I like the [LeSS approach to technical excellence](https://less.works/de/less/technical-excellence/index.html). A broad combination of quality practices.

Now in Agile teams, the question is not do we write tests or not, but who writes the test-cases. Developer should write test-cases, but testers could, product people could, anyone on the team could. Preferably the teams automate them aswell.

If your team does not have a nice balance of tests (unit, integration, and or end-2-end tests)  then they are taking serious shortcuts and are cowboy coding in my book. With a high risk of very slow development in the long run, as:

> Organizational Agility is constrained by Technical Agility
>
> https://less.works/de/less/technical-excellence/index.html

All Agile leaders suggest forms of testing in their writings, but I like those of [Robert C. Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin) the most. Be sure to read his [Clean Code series](https://cleancoders.com/) starting with [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882). Clean coders make tests period.

You are not Agile with just the process alone, I think we should talk more about the technical practices. An adaptable process is worthless if your product is not adaptable. Agile coding is all about refactoring and having a soft product that does not resist change. Testing is a strong part of this.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider time-boxed exploratory testing and risk-based testing - both approaches have their benefits and compliment each other if you're able to execute them both.

[**Exploratory testing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_testing) is an approach to software testing that is concisely described as simultaneous learning, test design and test execution.

[**Risk-based testing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk-based_testing) functions as an organisational principle used to prioritise the tests of features and functions in software, based on the risk of failure, the function of their importance and likelihood or impact of failure.

The latter is especially useful when pushed for time, as you're able to test the highest risk areas and have confidence that no high priority / severity defects exist in the product before handing over to the client.